# scenarios of openflow in omnet are not working properly

Tags: sdn, openflow

I download openflow. It successfully been built. However, only scenario_Small is correctly working, when try to run other scenarios error runtime appears such as that:

> Cannot add statistic 'numOutOfOrderArrivals' to module MultiController.Vancouver.client[0].pingApp[0] (NED type: openflow.apps.PingAppRandom): Error in source=numOutOfOrderArrivals: Signal 'numOutOfOrderArrivals' is not declared on type 'openflow.apps.PingAppRandom' (you can turn off this check by adding checkSignals=false to the @statistic property in the NED file) -- in module (PingAppRandom) MultiController.Vancouver.client[0].pingApp[0] (id=161), during network setup

when trying to run "szenario_Domains_multiController"
I tried to fix the error following the hint mentioned in error, but another errors appeared. How to fix those endless errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the codebase of [this](https://github.com/lsinfo3/ofomnet) openflow project is already old and does not correspond to the new builds of OmNET++ and the INET framework.
I was success to build and run test scenarios from [this](https://github.com/CoRE-RG/OpenFlow) project on Win 10 and OmNET++ 5.6.2 and INET 3.6.6.